# Why wamp server doesn't work on localhost?

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin, localhost, wamp

[image]

[image]

I successfully installed wamp-manager in my device, but when I run it in browser localhost doesn't work. I have tried to change the port from 8081 to 80, 8080, or another port, but it doesn't work anyway. Please, help me! I'm literally dying inside if I can't work with my website. I have tried Wamp Server.

Comment: What u see is IIS, not wamp .

Comment: You have IIS installed and as it probably gets started automatically at boot, it will have grabbed port 80 before you can start WAMPServer. If you are not using IIS then look up how to stop it, or better still uninstall it and get some resources back